# Change innerHTML individually from multiple text-field with same ID from multiple span

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the value form a multiple span and change multiple text-field. All have the same ID and Class and they should change it individually, every text-field with their span in order. I can't change the HTML, only the javascript. This JSFiddle show that for now I only can change all at the same time with the first span. Thank you:

http://jsfiddle.net/1q95yk6f/

**HTML:**

```
   <textarea class="field-element" id="iText" aria-required="true">Change TEXT 1</textarea>
<div class="iSpan">
    <span><span>Text 1</span>
    </span>
</div>

<textarea class="field-element" id="iText" aria-required="true">Change TEXT 2</textarea>
<div class="iSpan">
    <span><span>Text 2</span>
    </span>
</div>

<textarea class="field-element" id="iText" aria-required="true">Change TEXT 3</textarea>
<div class="iSpan">
    <span><span>Text 3</span>
    </span>
</div>


<br> <button type="button" onclick="Change();">Click Me!</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function Change () {
var items = document.getElementById( 'iText' );
 var divs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'iSpan' );

[].slice.call( divs ).forEach(function ( div ) {
    div.innerHTML = items.value;
});
}
```

Comment: HTML requires ids to be unique - you should not have several elements with the same id, if you do they are basically useless (though browsers will probably always give you the first one they come across).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I know but is a website that have their own ID and Classes and works like that, for that reason I can't change the HTML. The problem isn't that, is how to solve the problem of the question

Comment: Well, the problem is that, in terms of the JS you have in that it gets the same items element each time, and therefore the same value - however no need for despair, there's always a way!

Comment: Is textarea.field-element going to be unique enough as a selector to get the 4 textareas or do such pop up elsewhere?

Comment: It is get it from a pop up on every span individually

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each textarea has the same id so this cannot be used as a normal selector - in most browsers it will just give the first one.

One way of selecting given the code in the question is to use textarea.field-element as in this snippet - with a little extra checking that we are getting the right ones by checking that the textarea and the div are next to each other (siblings).

```js
function Change () {
  let divs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'iSpan' );
  let textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea.field-element');
  let items = [];
  let k = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
    if ( divs[k] == textareas[i].nextElementSibling) { items[k] = textareas[i]; k++; }
  }
 
  if (divs.length != items.length) { alert('The number of divs does not match the number of textareas'); }
  else {
    for (let j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
       divs[j].innerHTML = items[j].value;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
   <textarea class="field-element" id="iText" aria-required="true">Change TEXT 1</textarea>
<div class="iSpan">
    <span><span>Text 1</span>
    </span>
</div>

<textarea class="field-element" id="iText" aria-required="true">Change TEXT 2</textarea>
<div class="iSpan">
    <span><span>Text 2</span>
    </span>
</div>

<textarea class="field-element" id="iText" aria-required="true">Change TEXT 3</textarea>
<div class="iSpan">
    <span><span>Text 3</span>
    </span>
</div>


<br> <button type="button" onclick="Change();">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. The code works but not in the website. Maybe if the code could check if I'm clicking on the first or the second or the third SPAN, then it can get the value from the field-element "iText" in the same position of them and change only that, like change one by one. Do you think this can be implemented?

Comment: Sorry I don't completely understand. What is it that is to be changed, and to what value? The code in the question overwrites the spans - do you want them to remain?

Comment: Sorry, my fault explaining what I mean, english is not my main language. The code perfectly overwrites all the spans at the same time when I click on the button, but in the website first I click on the span, then the span open a pop up showing the field-text and when that happend the code get the text from the field-text and overwrites the span. Like I press the button but every span is a button. With that, maybe if I click on every span, the code will check if the span clicked is the first one, or the second, and then overwrite that span with the field-text in the same position on the span